# Access Amazon RDS from EC2 instance from differenct region

Tags: amazon-ec2, sql-server-2012, amazon-rds

I can access an RDS instance from an EC2 instance in the same region. I have an Amazon RDS instance, for example, running in the California region. But I can not access the RDS from an EC2 in the Singapore region. It shows me the following error '**The underlying provider failed on open**'. How do I configure it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this, however you will need to open the RDS security group to the IP your instance is connecting from. Security group based rules only work within a region.

Comment: Please be a more specific .

Comment: Your ec2 instance has a public ip address with which it makes outgoing connections. This ip address needs to be opened in the RDS security groups.

Comment: Security groups are located under the EC2 security group section now. You will need to edit that and add the public ip address (e.g. the elastic ip) for the ec2 instance you want to communicate with.